Setsar и setdar в ffmpeg
Изначальное видео имеет SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9
 Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: av1 (libdav1d) (Main) (av01 / 0x31307661), yuv420p10le(tv, bt2020nc/bt2020/smpte2084), 3840x2160, 25542 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn (default)

Выполняю команду setsar=1:1,setdar=16:9
ffmpeg -i {file} -cpu-used 8 -c:v libaom-av1 -vf scale=-2:240,fps=10,setsar=1:1,setdar=16:9 -crf 30 -b:v 2000k /tttt.mkv

И получаю на выходе SAR 360:71 DAR 9:1
Stream #0:0: Video: av1 (libdav1d) (Main), yuv420p10le(tv, bt2020nc/bt2020/smpte2084, progressive), 426x240, SAR 360:71 DAR 9:1, 10 fps, 10 tbr, 1k tbn (default)

Ок, выполняю setsar=1:1
ffmpeg -i {file} -cpu-used 8 -c:v libaom-av1 -vf scale=-2:240,fps=10,setsar=1:1 -crf 30 -b:v 2000k /tttt.mkv

Получаем SAR 1:1 DAR 71:40
 Stream #0:0: Video: av1 (libdav1d) (Main), yuv420p10le(tv, bt2020nc/bt2020/smpte2084, progressive), 426x240, SAR 1:1 DAR 71:40, 10 fps, 10 tbr, 1k tbn (default)

Скачал на ютубе, все разрешения одного и того же видео и у всех SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9
Не понимаю, что дают данные значение, второе вероятно соотношение сторон. Но если у ютуба на все одно и тоже, значит должно быть SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9
Собственно как добиться того же, при условии что высота кадра фиксированная а ширина адаптивная под всоту.
И да, что значит [0x1](und) в первом примере кода?

Ну как минимум задаваемые вами значения setsar/setdar не соответствуют примерам из документации, что скорее всего означает, что вы делаете это неправильно https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Examples-119

Кстати, вы ещё и видео с ютуба проверяли невнимательно: скачайте видео конкретно в качестве 240p, и вы увидите, что DAR там будет вовсе не 16:9

Правы, 240 другое и на 480, на 144 еще не знаю. Но у всех sar 1:1.

На что необходимо смотреть, чтобы верно выставить dar?

Ну собственно setsar=sar=1 должно быть достаточно

Работает, еще вопрос небольшой по -profile main  на всех main, за исключением 720/1080/2160. На что смотреть необходимо, чтобы верно выставлять данный параметр или он тоже автоматом ставиться отталкиваясь от предыдущих параметров?
